# Error while installing Python virtual environment for ESP-IDF using the Espressif IDF extension for Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, esp32, espressif-idf

I tried to install ESP-IDF and its tools with the Visual Studio Code extension but I got errors because there are spaces in my user name in Windows (I'm using Windows 10).

So I used the online installer version 2.16; it installed all the components in `C:\Espressif`. I set the system variable `IDF_PATH` to this location.

I open Visual Studio Code and the USE EXISTING SETUP option is available; it says:
"We have found ESP-IDF version: 4.4.2 @C:/Espressif/frameworks/esp-idf-v4.4.2/ and ESP-IDF tools in @ C:\Espressif. Click here to use them."

It puts a check mark in:

- Installing IDF Prerequisites...
- Installing ESP-IDF...
- Installing ESP-IDF Tools...

But it fails in Installing Python virtual environment for ESP-IDF...

The output window shows this:

```
idf_versions.txt has (1) KB
idf_versions.txt progress: 100.00% (0.10 / 0.10) KB
Installing ESP-IDF extension python packages in C:/Espressif/python_env/idf4.4_py3.8_env/Scripts/python.exe ...


ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\Users\\Axel'
Command failed: "C:/Espressif/python_env/idf4.4_py3.8_env/Scripts/python.exe" -m pip install --upgrade --constraint c:\Users\Axel Bryan\.vscode\extensions\espressif.esp-idf-extension-1.5.0\espidf.constraints.txt --no-warn-script-location  -r "c:\Users\Axel Bryan\.vscode\extensions\espressif.esp-idf-extension-1.5.0\requirements.txt"
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\Users\\Axel'
```

I tried tinkering with `IDF_PATH` and `IDF_TOOLS_PATH`, but it seems that at least one of them should be set to `C:\Espressif` to make the USE EXISTING SETUP option appear in VSCode.

Comment: I know this is not the answer you are looking for, and I'm sorry for that. I add it to the pool of information as it may still be useful to you or to the next reader... but basically... I have found no end to problems using VSCode with espressif's ESP-IDF. (not the least of which is that VSCode doesn't support multiple monitors very well) I find that using Eclipse CDT, and manually installing the IDF plugin to be much more functional system. This is also more inline with Espressif's preferred use case, as their IDE is based on Eclipse CDT. (Their IDE is also viable, FWIW)